# How to return a value from a function but keeping the function "alive" c#

Tags: c#, function, return

I have a function in a DLL that I've created that executes SQL commands and returns the path file from where they were executed, the number of commands with errors and the number of commands executed sucessfully all in a 3 pos. array.
The problem is that it only returns when the foreach ends wich will only allow me to present in a text box in the form the last executed file, and I need to show the file path as they are executed.

> I need a way to return the array everytime the foreach iterates but keeping >the function alive so it executes the rest of the commands in the next >files, this is the function:

```
public string[] ExecuteCommands(string Directoria, CdpsiUpdateSql Updater, CdpsiUpdateSqlparser parser, string Log)
        {

            string[] numArray1 = new string[3];
            List<string> list = ((IEnumerable<string>)Directory.GetFiles(Directoria, "*.sql", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)).Select(f =>
            {
                string[] strArray = Path.GetFileName(f).Split('_');
                int result;
                if (strArray.Length < 1 || !int.TryParse(strArray[0], out result))
                    result = -1;
                var data = new
                {
                    File = f,
                    Version = result
                };
                return data;
            }).Where(f => f.Version > -1).OrderBy(f => f.Version).Select(f => f.File).ToList<string>();
            foreach (string str in list)
            {
                int[] numArray2 = this.ExecuteCommand(parser.Parser(str), Updater, str, Log);
                int Certos = Convert.ToInt32(numArray1[0]);
                int Errados = Convert.ToInt32(numArray1[1]);
                Certos  += numArray2[0];
                Errados += numArray2[1];
                numArray1[0] = Certos.ToString();
                numArray1[1] = Errados.ToString();
                numArray1[2] = str;

            }
            return numArray1;
        }
```

Any help will be higly aprecciated, thank you

---

using yield?

```
public IEnumerable<string []> ExecuteCommands(string Directoria, CdpsiUpdateSql Updater, CdpsiUpdateSqlparser parser, string Log)
        {

            string[] numArray1 = new string[3];
            List<string> list = ((IEnumerable<string>)Directory.GetFiles(Directoria, "*.sql", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)).Select(f =>
            {
                string[] strArray = Path.GetFileName(f).Split('_');
                int result;
                if (strArray.Length < 1 || !int.TryParse(strArray[0], out result))
                    result = -1;
                var data = new
                {
                    File = f,
                    Version = result
                };
                return data;
            }).Where(f => f.Version > -1).OrderBy(f => f.Version).Select(f => f.File).ToList<string>();
            foreach (string str in list)
            {
                int[] numArray2 = this.ExecuteCommand(parser.Parser(str), Updater, str, Log);
                int Certos = Convert.ToInt32(numArray1[0]);
                int Errados = Convert.ToInt32(numArray1[1]);
                Certos  += numArray2[0];
                Errados += numArray2[1];
                numArray1[0] = Certos.ToString();
                numArray1[1] = Errados.ToString();
                numArray1[2] = str;
                yield return numArray1;
            }
            //return numArray1;
        }
```

Comment: First of all make a class to hold result (`class CommandResult { public int Certos; public int Errados, public string Command; }`) and then return an `IEnumerable<CommandResult>` then post it on Code Review, there are some nice things you can do to make this code easier to read.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti can you please add an example?
if I return the IEnumerable wont the function end when reached the return?

Comment: Yes but you hold results in a `List<CommandResult>` or you use `yield return` syntax.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Ok I've added that class

Comment: I would bet on yield, but does it apply to my problem?

Comment: Stupid question but why you don't return string[][] with all posible files at once?

Comment: @Logman because he wants to return them at _every iteration_ instead of _after all iterations_.

Comment: @RenéVogt "The problem is that it only returns when the foreach ends wich will only allow me to present in a text box in the form the last executed file, and I need to show the file path as they are executed.". Probably he asked wrong question. What I understand he want to have whole list of strings at the end. LikeIfYouCaredAboutMyName please clarify.

Comment: @Logman I want to return the number of successful commands, the number of commands with error and the path ("str" if you look at the foreach) in the end of every foreach iteration, but without ending the function (If I use a normal return after " numArray1[2] = str;" it will stop the function and I dont want that, I want to return those values but keep the function running so it executes the rest of the commands for the next files).

Comment: @LikeIfYouCaredAboutMyName I don't want to ruin your application concept but just tell me why you can't return all of your data at ones (as for ex. list<string[]>) and than access it as for ex. allData[3][2] (forth command path)? It is completely valid to do what you want as generator (yield) but from your code and your question I don't see what you will gain if you do so.

Comment: @Logman because I need to show in the main form the file path from wich the scripts are being executed and the number of successful executed commands and the ones with error, I need to show it as they are executed and not at the end. At the end of being executed as no purpose for me

Comment: Ok I see it now, for some reason I don't get meaning of this.ExecuteCommand. And what is wrong with generator approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I would define a better type for the result like that:

```
public struct Result
{
    public string File;
    public int Errors;
    public int Successes;
}
```

And then you could add a [`IProgress<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) parameter to your dll method:
And use this as an extra argument to your dll method:

```
public void ExecuteCommands(string Directoria, CdpsiUpdateSql Updater, CdpsiUpdateSqlparser parser, string Log, IProgress<Result> progress)
{
    //... your code

    foreach (string str in list)
    {
        int[] numArray2 = this.ExecuteCommand(parser.Parser(str), Updater, str, Log);
        // your code

        Result result = new Result
        {
            File = str,
            Error = Errados,
            Successes = Certos
        };
        progress.Report(result);
    }
}
```

On the *calling site* you create an instance of [`Progress<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like that:

```
Progress<Result> progress = new Progress<Result>(HandleProgress);
ExecuteCommands(Directoria, Updater, parser, Log, progress);
```

And implement a `HandleProgress` method like that:

```
private void HandleProgress(Result result)
{
    /* use the values in result to update your UI */
    Refresh(); // refresh the controls you updated
}
```

**Note** however that your `ExecuteCommands` runs *synchronously*. So your UI thread is blocked and changes to the controls are not immediatly drawn. Therefor I added that `Refresh()` statement, but its exact implementation depends a little on the controls you are about to update.

The `yield/IEnumerable` approach is a good one, too. But I still would suggest a proper `Result` type. The consumers of your method will never know what information is contained in that string array. And the problem with the blocked UI thread will be the same.

Comment: @LikeIfYouCaredAboutMyName yes, this is also a good approach. But I'd still suggest to define a proper `Result` type instead of using a string array.

Comment: Ìm a really confused with the usage of your method, Im relatively new to this srry :\

`Progress<Result> progress = new Progress<Result>(result => /* do something with the result */);`
this would be declared outside the function in the main form correct?

Comment: it's only "reporting" when the foreach ends, it only shows info for the last file executed :\

Comment: @LikeIfYouCaredAboutMyName Are you sure the `progress.Report` is _inside_ your `foreach`? Are you sure that it's only reporting at the end or is the problem that your UI won't update until your method stops blocking the UI thread? Did you debug it?

Comment: progree.Report is indeed inside the foreach, I think the problem is the UI locking, how can I update the UI?

Comment: ok I've debugging and I found something really really weird, the function 
`private void HandleProgress(CpdisUpdateScripts.Result result)` only executes at the end and updates everything just at the end and not file by file. That's why I only get to see the values about the last file executed.

Comment: @LikeIfYouCaredAboutMyName that totally depends on what UI framework you use and which controls you need to update. This is too broad to answer in comments. It may also be better to run your method asynchronously using `Task` or something, but as I said, too broad for comments.

Comment: instead of doing this:


`Progress<Result> progress = new Progress<Result>(HandleProgress);
ExecuteCommands(Directoria, Updater, parser, Log, progress);`

Can't I call `HandleProgress()` after `ExecuteCommands()` so it updates the info on the labels and text boxes?

Answer (score 0):

You can move your return statement into the foreach loop and use yield

```
foreach (string str in list)
            {
                int[] numArray2 = this.ExecuteCommand(parser.Parser(str), Updater, str, Log);
                int Certos = Convert.ToInt32(numArray1[0]);
                int Errados = Convert.ToInt32(numArray1[1]);
                Certos  += numArray2[0];
                Errados += numArray2[1];
                numArray1[0] = Certos.ToString();
                numArray1[1] = Errados.ToString();
                numArray1[2] = str;

                yield return numArray1;
            }
```

Comment: Even if it solves immediate OP's problem...I would not suggest to return numbers as strings just because one of them is a string. If you post an answer I'd address the multiple issues of that code (and I'd add some explanation about suggested solution...)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I only added the numbers as strings because I needed to return all the values at once, I actually thought firts to return a struct, can you please see my updated question?

Comment: @LikeIfYouCaredAboutMyName René's solution is pretty good. You may decide to use or not the callback function (returning instead an IEnumerable) but the point is to introduce a struct. Not just because of proper typing (int instead of string) but because accessing result[1] you can't see (at calling point) which field you're reading (moreover you can make it read-only, if you want). When you have a working solution I strongly suggest to post it on Code Review and you will get many useful tips!

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide you with some alternatives. You can try using delegate/ lambda

```
public void ExecuteCommands(string Directoria, CdpsiUpdateSql Updater, CdpsiUpdateSqlparser parser, string Log, Action<int[]> getResults)
{

    string[] numArray1 = new string[3];
    List<string> list = ((IEnumerable<string>)Directory.GetFiles(Directoria, "*.sql", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)).Select(f =>
    {
        string[] strArray = Path.GetFileName(f).Split('_');
        int result;
        if (strArray.Length < 1 || !int.TryParse(strArray[0], out result))
            result = -1;
        var data = new
        {
            File = f,
            Version = result
        };
        return data;
    }).Where(f => f.Version > -1).OrderBy(f => f.Version).Select(f => f.File).ToList<string>();
    foreach (string str in list)
    {
        int[] numArray2 = this.ExecuteCommand(parser.Parser(str), Updater, str, Log);
        int Certos = Convert.ToInt32(numArray1[0]);
        int Errados = Convert.ToInt32(numArray1[1]);
        Certos += numArray2[0];
        Errados += numArray2[1];
        numArray1[0] = Certos.ToString();
        numArray1[1] = Errados.ToString();
        numArray1[2] = str;

        //new code
        if(getResults!=null)
        {
            getResults(numArray1);
        }
    }

}
```

Usage in your main call will then be:

```
int totalResults=0;
Action<int[]> doSomething = (results)=>
    {
        //do some work whenever results is returned, e.g
        totalResults+=results.Sum();
    };
ExecuteCommands(directoria, parser, updater, log, doSomething);
```

Comment: But will that update the UI values or will the UI be locked and will only update at the end?
I've ran the function in a task to make it async, so far so good but I've ran into a problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588186/values-resetting-back-to-zero-after-task-is-completed-c-sharp

Comment: I looked at your other qns. I think your problem might be because you are updating your UI in the task/thread, which may ve causing race conditions because the main UI thread might also be performing updates. Let me do some tests and get back to you in a couple of hrs

Comment: thank you a lot, Im really lost on this one. I've already tried everything I could remember

Comment: @LikeIfYouCaredAboutMyName I have created the answer in your new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588186/values-resetting-back-to-zero-after-task-is-completed-c-sharp/37593963#37593963

Hope that will solve your problem