# Values "resetting" back to zero after Task is completed C#

Tags: c#, variables, task, handler

This is my function, it returns a struct with the number of successful commands, the number of the ones with errors and also the total
of both and also the file path from wich they are being exectued in a Iprogress interface.

```
   public void ExecuteCommands(string Directories, CdpsiUpdateSql Updater, CdpsiUpdateSqlparser parser, string Log, IProgress<Result> progress)
        {
            Result FinalResult = new Result();
            int totalWithErrors = 0;
            int totalSuccess = 0;
            string[] numArray1 = new string[3];
            List<string> list = ((IEnumerable<string>)Directory.GetFiles(Directories, "*.sql", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)).Select(f =>
            {
                string[] strArray = Path.GetFileName(f).Split('_');
                int result;
                if (strArray.Length < 1 || !int.TryParse(strArray[0], out result))
                    result = -1;
                var data = new
                {
                    File = f,
                    Version = result
                };
                return data;
            }).Where(f => f.Version > -1).OrderBy(f => f.Version).Select(f => f.File).ToList<string>();
            foreach (string str in list)
            {
                int[] numArray2 = this.ExecuteCommand(parser.Parser(str), Updater, str, Log);
                int Succcesses = numArray2[0];
                int Errors = numArray2[1];
                //totalWithErrors += Errors;
                //totalSuccess += Succcesses;

                FinalResult.File = str;
                FinalResult.Errors = Errors;
                FinalResult.Successes = Errors;
                //FinalResult.TotalWithErrors = totalWithErrors;
                //FinalResult.totalSuccess = totalSuccess;


                progress.Report(FinalResult);
            }
        }
```

In my main code I call the function like this:

```
foreach (var ConnectionString in ConnectionStrings)
        {
            connection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString);
            using (CdpsiUpdateSql NewUpdater = new CdpsiUpdateSql(connection))
            {
                labelBDver.Text = Global.VersaoBd = NewUpdater.LookUp("GGDSC", "APPLCONFIG", "GGCOD = 'APP_NAME'");
                lbVersao.Text = "Versão: " + Global.NovaVersao;
                CpdisUpdateScripts Scripts = new CpdisUpdateScripts();
                CdpsiUpdateSqlparser Parser = new CdpsiUpdateSqlparser();
                var progressHandler = new Progress<CpdisUpdateScripts.Result>(result =>
                {
                    textBox1.Text = result.File;
                    //Global.TotalExecCerros = result.TotalWithErrors;
                    //Global.TotalExecSuccessfull = result.totalSuccess;
                    Global.TotalExecCerros += result.Errors;
                    Global.TotalExecSuccessfull += result.Successes;
                    labelErrorCommandCnt.Text = result.Errors.ToString();
                    labelSuccessfulCnt.Text = result.Successes.ToString();
                    Refresh();

                });
                IProgress<CpdisUpdateScripts.Result> progress = progressHandler;
                Task MyTask = Task.Run(() =>
                {

                    Scripts.ExecuteCommands(Global.Update + @"\scripts", NewUpdater, Parser,
                        Global.Update + @"\scripts", progress);

                });

            }
        }
```

> On the handler, the values that are passed to the labels are correct, the labels recive the correct values and the Global.Cerros and Global.TotalExecSuccessfull = result.totalSuccess; also recieve the correct number of errors, but when the foreach finishes both are 0.
>               I can't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Make any varublw which you want to hold a value permanently static or save it to the gui and read it baxk each time

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking, really. This needs a [mcve].  Your best option is to step through with a debugger to work out where whatever it is that's wrong is set to the wrong value.  As an aside, your `Task.Run` is pretty pointless if you're just going to block and wait straight after it.

Comment: @CharlesMager I've just added the await to see if it would change anything, the task is working just fine and doing what I actually needed, just that values going to 0 after it executes, i'ts that Im not getting the "why"
Im asking why the value of the Global. vars go back to 0 when the foreach ends. It doesnt make sense that they get the correct value but go back to 0

Comment: @Shon the variables are in a class declared like this:


`public static int TotalExecCerros { get; set; }
public static int TotalExecSuccessfull { get; set; }`

Comment: @LikeIfYouCaredAboutMyName it's not clear what 'values' are being set to zero and where, let alone why, hence the request for a [mcve].  Though I'd suspect in trying to create one you'd proably discover what the problem is.

Comment: The instance of the class is to be static

Comment: Should you not be *adding* to those totals instead of just setting them to the last result?

Comment: @CharlesMager they are added in the function. I've had like you're saying previously... same result, they get the value but go back to 0

Comment: Are you reusing the same instance of the class or a new one each time

Comment: @Shon it's always the same one. Since the class is part of my project, I just access it by Global.

Comment: Declare a varible as the class and thenuse thw varible. Accessing the class directly can create new instances of the class

Comment: @Shon but oyu can't create instances of static classes

Comment: @LikeIfYouCaredAboutMyName They are added *per connection string*.  Every time you loop, they get reset to zero. `ExecuteCommands` starts with the total as zero each time.

Comment: @CharlesMager yes I totally understand that, but the Global.Cerros shouldnt be reseted, it's just adding up the values. what do I need to change? Im a little lost

Comment: @LikeIfYouCaredAboutMyName no it isn't, you *set* it to the result in your progress handler, so you overwrite it every time. If you want to add each result, you need `Global.TotalExecCerros += result.TotalWithErrors`.

Comment: @CharlesMager ok I've changed it to that now

Comment: I return the number of erros and I will sum them up in the handler

Comment: @LikeIfYouCaredAboutMyName We're basically back to guessing now.  You need to make your question clearer.  Read [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @CharlesMager Im not sure on how can I be more clearer than this. I've showed the code, and what my problem is, and explained what it does and

Comment: Read the links I gave you, particularly on how to create a [mcve].  There's a lot of code that isn't relevant to the problem, and no one can take this code and compile it to reproduce your issue as it wouldn't compile.

Comment: but that's impossible really, to be able to reproduce it I would have to paste all DLLS here wich I really can't :\

Comment: It's not impossible, you just have to go through it.  You don't need any of the SQL code, for example, it can be reduced to a very basic logic problem.  It's pretty unclear what the problem is from your explanation or code, however.

Comment: wish I could move this chat but ok I will try to explain as best as I can:

Ok let's start, I have a function that will return an Iprogress interface of a struct that contains the number of commands with errors, the number of the successfull ones and the file path from wich they are being executed. The code in the function is well written, Im sure of that.
In the main form I call that function via a task and in the handler of that task I update two labels and a text box with the values from the struct.
They are updated with the **correct value**,

Comment: the variables that sum up those values are also summing it up correctly, **but when the foreach ends they are as they were never affected, their value is set to 0**. So if the labels are updated with the correct values and the vars are as well why they are set to 0 as they were never affected when the foreach ends?
This is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your `IProgress.Report(FinalResult)`. You need to create a new copy of the Result object everytime when passing it to `IProgress.Report` method.

So to solve your problem, you need to change you code as follows:

```cs
public void ExecuteCommands(string Directories, CdpsiUpdateSql Updater, CdpsiUpdateSqlparser parser, string Log, IProgress<Result> progress)
{
    //Remove this line
    //Result FinalResult = new Result();

    //... your code as is... bla bla bla

    foreach (string str in list)
    {
        int[] numArray2 = this.ExecuteCommand(parser.Parser(str), Updater, str, Log);
        int Succcesses = numArray2[0];
        int Errors = numArray2[1];

        //new line
        Result FinalResult = new Result();
        FinalResult.File = str;
        FinalResult.Errors = Errors;
        FinalResult.Successes = Errors;

        progress.Report(FinalResult);

    }
}
```

Comment: same problem, the labels are updated correctly, the variables too but then they are IDK what happens but their value is set to 0.
Maybe something in my handler? something I really dont know.

Comment: What are you doing in your `Refresh()` method? By the way i noticed in your code you had `FinalResult.Successes = Errors`, is this intentional?